# How to check if the hypervisor present bit is set using CPUID

Tags: linux, cpu, x86

I currently have problems determining if the hypervisor bit (31 bit) is set to true using CPUID on command line.

I'm using the following command `cpuid -1 -r` to retrieve the hex data as shown in the screenshot below.

I'm unsure how exactly to retrieve the hypervisor bit value from this list of hex values.

Any help on solving this problem would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the textual representation given by `cpuid` by default:

```
cpuid -1 | grep 'hypervisor guest status'
```

If you really want to use the raw values, you need to filter on CPUID#1 and then check that `ECX` is greater than or equal to 0x80000000:

```
cpuid -1 -r | grep '^   0x00000001.*ecx=0x[89a-f]'
```

If that produces output, the bit is set, otherwise it isn’t; you can also use `grep`'s exit status.